# How to generate only required fields from xsd using JAXB - apache cxf?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I need only the required fields to be in my Java classes from XSD. So I want to generate Java classes from XSD using JAX-B or Apache CXF, but only required fields. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to generate Java classes from an XML schema containing only required fields [using `xjc`](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html).  (Note: `cxf-xjc-plugin` is just a wrapper around `xjc`.)  There are a couple of options though:

1) Use `xjc` and then use reflection to find fields annotated with `@XmlElement(required = true)`;

2) Use an XSLT to transform the input schema, for example by removing elements with the `minOccurs="0"` attribute (indicating that they're optional).